# JQuery Ajax - Code did work now it does not?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I built a basic form with ajax validation and page redirection with PHP and jQuery. This was working fine a few days back. I have come back to it and the ajax seems to have stopped working. At the moment the ajax is just checking a test var and echoing back data. It is really bugging me as it working fine initially! Seems strange as I cannot spot anything obvious, hoping some fresh eyes can help.

The ajax has stopped sending data across so I click submit and the ajax sends nothing so my if() does not do anything! I get the form values fine. Tried with basic ajax and alerts, something strange seems to be happening.

Hope you can help

```
 <form id="registerform">
        <ul id="form">
        <li>
        <label for="email">Email:</label><span class="fieldbox"><input type="text" id="email"/></span>
        </li>
        <li>
        <label for="confirmemail">Confirm Email:</label><span class="fieldbox"><input type="text" id="confirmemail"/></span>
        </li>
        <li>
        <label for="password">Password:</label> <span class="fieldbox"> <input type="password" id="password"/></span>
        </li>
        <li>
        <label for="confirmpassword">Confirm Password:</label> <span class="fieldbox"> <input type="confirmpassword" id="confirmpassword"/></span>
        </li>
        <input type="submit" id="register" value="Sign me up!"/>
        </ul>
 </form>



<div id="errorbox"></div>
```

jQuery:

```
   $(document).ready(function(){

           $("#register").click(function(){

           var formvalues = [$("#email").val(), $("#confirmemail").val(), $("#password").val(), $("#confirmpassword").val() ];
           var checklength = formvalues[2].length;


                    if(formvalues[0] == "" || formvalues[1] == ""){
                        $('#errorbox').fadeIn('slow');
                        $("#errorbox").html('<p class="errormsg">Please complete email fields.</p><div class="errormsgshodow"></div>');
                         $("#main").shake(3, 5, 600);
                        return false;//stop click function
                    }

                    if(formvalues[2] == "" ||  formvalues[3] == ""){
                       $('#errorbox').fadeIn('slow');
                        $("#errorbox").html('<p class="errormsg">Please complete password fields.</p><div class="errormsgshodow"></div>');
                         $("#main").shake(3, 5, 600);
                        return false;//stop click function
                    }

                   if(formvalues[0] != formvalues[1]){
                        $('#errorbox').fadeIn('slow');
                        $("#errorbox").html('<p class="errormsg">Password field do not match</p><div class="errormsgshodow"></div>');
                         $("#main").shake(3, 5, 600);
                        return false;//stop click function
                    }

                    if(formvalues[2] != formvalues[3]){
                        $('#errorbox').fadeIn('slow');
                        $("#errorbox").html('<p class="errormsg">Password field do not match</p><div class="errormsgshodow"></div>');
                         $("#main").shake(3, 5, 600);
                        return false;//stop click function
                    }

                     if(checklength < 6 || checklength > 6){
                         $('#errorbox').fadeIn('slow');
                         $("#errorbox").html('<p class="errormsg">Password is too long.</p><div class="errormsgshodow"></div>');
                          $("#main").shake(3, 5, 600);
                         return false;//stop click function   
                    }

                    var datastring = 'email=' + formvalues[1] + '&password=' + formvalues[3];

                       $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "signup.php",
                        data: datastring,
                                      success: function(data){
                                         //see redirect script for stuff here
                                         if(data != "error"){
                                         window.location="http://localhost/creativetree/projectboard.php?id="+data;
                                         }else{
                                         $('#errorbox').fadeIn('slow');
                                         $("#errorbox").html('<p class="errormsg">User account already exists with that email.</p><div class="errormsgshodow"></div>');;
                                         }



                                     }

                       });

           });

  });//jquery end






           //shake functions by Amit Dhamu
           jQuery.fn.shake = function(intShakes /*Amount of shakes*/, intDistance /*Shake distance*/, intDuration /*Time duration*/) {
                this.each(function() {
                     $(this).css({position:"relative"});

                     for (var x=1; x<=intShakes; x++) {
                          $(this).animate({left:(intDistance*-1)}, (((intDuration/intShakes)/4)))
                                       .animate({left:intDistance}, ((intDuration/intShakes)/2))
                                       .animate({left:0}, (((intDuration/intShakes)/4)));
                     }
                });
                return this;
           };
```

And minimal PHP for result:

```
  <?php


    if(isset($_POST['email'])){

        $email =  $_POST['email'];
        $password =  $_POST['password'];

                    if($email == "test"){
                        echo $email;
                    }else{
                          echo 'error';      
                    }
    }


    ?>
```

Comment: Oops! you forgot to mention what doesn't work..., What exactly doesn't work?

Comment: Try using "Charles Proxy" to narrow it down. "Charles" is nice app to help determine what data is being sent back and forth between the client and Server. At least this way you can determine if the data being sent is valid, if its sending at all. and if it is being sent, determine if the server isn't just  bugging out.

Comment: sorry ajax has just stopped working, I get form values but when I send them using ajax my if is not responding as if it has stopped working. Tryed basic ajax with alerts and nothing seems to be doing much.

Comment: Are you seeing network traffic using FireBug or Chrome's tools or IE's F12 tools?  Or, are you not seeing your page code being executed?  Just saying AJAX stopped working doesn't really help.  You should let us know what part isn't working -- is the request being sent but not processed, or is the request not even being sent?

Comment: from what i can see its not being sent. Firebug appears to not show any response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell without seeing the error you are receiving, but from what I can see, you are not returning anything from your function upon successful validation, so your form will be submitted normally as well.

You can prevent the form from submitting by using something like:

```
$("#registerform").submit(function() {
  return false;
});
```

but perhaps returning `false` from the submit button click handler is enough as well.

Comment: agreed. returning false in the click handler should do it.

Comment: It works but I am getting extra characters on the end of my data url output e.g. 'http://localhost/creativetree/projectboard.php?id=%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20test' Any ideas?

Comment: @sherwoodbear Seriously though, can you add a demo on for example jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: thanks I am going to look into my code more thanks for all the help. I have a feeling my mamp server is doing some weird things.

Comment: @sherwoodbear Good luck, I would start with adding `console.log()` messages everywhere.

Comment: Answer: Just added this into my form submit button (which is what jeroen and Evan basically said). The way my code was set up it worked better as an inline javascript function.

onclick="return false"

One day I will spot these quicker! one day......

thanks for all the effort guys!